# MSAA -- Dragon Cannot Interact with TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility, tablelayoutpanel, naturallyspeaking

I am modifying a Winforms application to be accessible via Dragon Professional 15.  I have also recently added support for screen readers (including JAWS and MAGic) so the application has been, for the most part, reviewed in order to ensure that the **AccessibleName** (and, where appropriate, **AccessibleRole**) property is filled out.

Dragon does fairly well with most of this application but there are parts with which it utterly fails to operate.  After a lot of trial and error, I was able to determine that the cause of the problem was the use of **TableLayoutPanels** in my application.  Any control that resides in a **TableLayoutPanel** is not consumable by Dragon (ie. when I speak the **AccessibleName** value, Dragon cannot find the control).  As an example, the button in this document tree works just fine in the following configuration:

[image: working document configuration]

(NB: The **noFocusCueButton** class derives from **Button** and has only minor changes concerning visual aspects of the class.)

In this configuration, I can speak the **AccessibleName** of the **noFocusCueButton** and Dragon will recognize it and click it.  However, as soon as I move to this configuration:

[image: broken document configuration]

...Dragon can no longer detect and interact with the **noFocusCueButton**.  I have searched for some property on the **TableLayoutPanel** that might explain this but I do not see anything obvious.  I have also searched for other people encountering this problem but have not come up with anything.  Any SO experts out there know anything about this?

Comment: Child controls of a TLP are fully accessible by both MSAA and UI Automation. Their Role and Name properties of course don't change in any way. There is just one more level of nesting, in relation to the `Window` role of a child control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what can only be described as "the story of my life", I found the problem in less than a few minutes after posting the question (though I had spent hours on it beforehand).

Evidently, at some point, the **AccessibleRole** property of the **TableLayoutPanel** had been set to **List**.  Setting it back to **Default** fixed the problem.

Comment: nothing wrong in answering your own question :-) As a web only accessibility consultant stuff like this is great for when I alwyas get asked about application accessibility and have to fumble around like an idiot! +1